# 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'set_index'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.7

I have a dataFrame **data**. After grouping and resetting the index, I am not able to set my Date column as Index.

```
data = data.groupby('Payment Date ')
data['Payment Amount '].sum().reset_index()
```

[image: This is my output resetting index]

```
 data = data.set_index('Payment Date ', inplace  = True)
 data.index
```

Error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-581b0b0bf83f> in <module>
----> 1 data = data.set_index('Payment Date ', inplace  = True)
      2 data.index

c:\users\nitro\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in __getattr__(self, attr)
    702 
    703         raise AttributeError(
--> 704             f"'{type(self).__name__}' object has no attribute '{attr}'"
    705         )
    706 

AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'set_index'
```

Comment: What is not really clear is what you would expect after the setting of the index. `data` is a `DataFrameGroupBy` object, which does not hold any data. You need to apply an aggregation function (e.g. sum or mean) or some other transformation (e.g. rank) for it to have actual data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I understood what you wanted to do and what you did not understand (mainly about the way to modifiy objects with pandas). I assume that you wanted to:

1. compute your aggregation by payment date in `data`
2. and then set its index to 'Payment date' field

Short answer: if you want to have this result into `data`, simply execute:

```py
data = data.groupby('Payment date ')['Payment amount'].sum().to_frame()
```

'Payment date ' will be your new index, `to_frame` prevents your single column resulting dataframe to be squeezed into a pandas `Series` (which I think was your first intention to avoid, resetting your index to then set it back).

Let's dive into your code.

**First line**

```py
data = data.groupby('Payment Date ')
```

First line is ok, but might not do exactly what you want. You are taking `data`, which I assume is a pandas `DataFrame` and reaffect it a pandas `DataFrameGroupBy` object. This kind of object does not hold any data, you can see it simply as a mapping between index(s) of your original `DataFrame` and associated groups (here, payment dates).

Anyway, you got your groupby object into `data`.

**Second line**

```py
data['Payment Amount '].sum().reset_index()
```

This line does nothing. It shows the result of the computation in your Jupyter notebook, **but nothing has been changed in `data`**. `data` is still the same `DataFrameGroupBy` object.

**Third line**

```py
data = data.set_index('Payment Date ', inplace  = True)
```

An exception is raised, saying that a `DataFrameGroupBy` objet has no `set_index` method. This is because `data` has not been changed by your second line of code.
Even so, I would encourage you to *avoid* using `inplace=True` anytime in your code. You should always go with *explicit* reassignements.

Your code could look like (if you don't like the short answer above):

```py
data = data.groupby('Payment date ')
data = data['Payment amount'].sum().reset_index()
data = data.set_index('Payment date ')  # No inplace=True!
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining it in simple words!

Comment: I see you are new to SO, if what I wrote is the correct answer to your question, you should mark it as the accepted answer.